# What makes the complex rotation mapping a rotation mapping?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The complex rotation mapping is $z \mapsto e^{i \theta}z$ where $\theta$ is some angle of rotation.

I am doing a problem where $\theta = \frac \pi 4$. Using Euler's equation, I wrote $z \mapsto e^{i \frac \pi 4} z = (\cos(\frac \pi 4) + i \sin(\frac \pi 4)) z = -\frac 1 4 z$. So now it seems like the mapping is just $z \mapsto -\frac 1 4 z$, which is not a rotation mapping at all? It just scales the $z$ by $-\frac 1 4$. Thus, what makes this a rotation mapping?

Comment: I would calculate $\cos(\frac \pi 4) + i \sin(\frac \pi 4)$ one more time.

Comment: @Arthur oh I see! I was doing $\cos(\pi)/4$ in my calculator...